# "Each" (adverb): from each one

Tags: adverbs, dictionaries

> **Each** (adverb): to, **from**, or for each (one).
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/Each

However, I cannot come up with any example using the meaning "from".

Is such a meaning grammatical?

https://oed.com/oed2/00071471

Comment: What are the examples you have for the adverb use with the meaning "to" and "for"?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I gave them three each and They cost a dollar each

Comment: Ok. Here are the diet food group selections. To compose a healthy meal, take one each.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thanks. Is it productive with prepositions other than those three maybe?

Comment: I can't think of any other examples right now.

Comment: To my Canadian ear, for @JackO'Flaherty's example to have his intended meaning, it would have to read, "take one **of/from** each." To me, this has the meaning "Each of you people I'm talking to, please take one of the diet food group selections."

Comment: @gotube You have a point there. Can you think of an example where "each" would be an adverb with the sense "from each", that would be unambiguously that?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty After much brain scratching, "The defendants were ordered to pay $500 each to the plaintiff."

Comment: @gotube Good one!

Answer (score -1):

An example with the meaning of "from":

> The defendants paid $500 **each** to the plaintiff.

This sentence means $500 **from each** defendant was paid to the plaintiff.